# Is there any way of improving Doom graphics when running it on DOSBox?

Tags: video, graphics-card, gaming

I downloaded Ultimate DOOM a while ago on the Internet. That was when it was freely available but not now.

Now if we download only “Knee-Deep in the Dead” — which is the first part — is free.

Initially, this was fine but now the graphics display is very bad.

[image: Phobos Anomaly]

I don’t have any graphics card other that the built-in graphics provided by my Intel CPU.

Is there a way to improve the graphics?

Here are links to YouTube video which shows how bad is graphics on my system.

- [“Icon of Sin”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6LTAl9ujM0&t=295s)
- [“Tower of Babel”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0w-6watL1JM&t=28s)

Comment: So what is the issue? The blockiness of the graphics themselves? Because Doom was crated as a game before 3D graphics cards were a thing. These pixelated graphics are simply what they are: Blocky and pixelated graphics.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I know what your attempting to say, but technically, DOOM was a 3D game.  Was of the first actually, it’s one of the reasons, I am in the field I am in.

Comment: @Ramhound I respect that. But I said “3D graphics cards” that allowed for 3D vector graphics and not the 3D games like Doom attempted which were all raster graphics.

Comment: Like I said, I know what you were saying, Doom is around 30 years old at this point it’s graphics are not going to be amazing.

Comment: DooM was made long before 3D cards became a thing.  Hence lowres graphics.  You are being authentic here.

Comment: I'd say that's a matter of taste. Those graphics look hellishly good to me!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don’t like the blocky, rasterized graphics you are seeing when attempting to play Doom in DOSBox, the better alternative is to use a native OS interpreter of the Doom engine such as [GZDoom](https://zdoom.org/about); a newer and maintained GNU licnesed version of ZDoom. These modern Doom engines use the vector graphics capabilities of modern systems. As they describe on their websites:

> “ZDoom is a family of enhanced ports of the Doom engine for running on modern operating systems. It runs on Windows, Linux, and OS X, and adds new features not found in the games as originally published by id Software.”
>
> “Older ZDoom ports may be used and distributed free of charge. No profit may be made from the sale of it. GZDoom and its descendants from version 3.0.0 on are licensed GPL and are subject to the terms and restrictions of the new license.”

Installing GZDoom is fairly easy and [explained clearly on the ZDoom Wiki](https://zdoom.org/wiki/Installation_and_execution_of_ZDoom). You just need to be sure to have the WAD files you need to play. They even have a [very good overview of all of the WAD files you can use with ZDoom](https://zdoom.org/wiki/IWAD).

> “An IWAD - short for *Internal WAD* - is the main resource file for a Doom-engine game, containing all the game's original sounds, levels, and graphics. ZDoom needs an IWAD file in order to play; without one the ZDoom engine has no game data to use.”

If you have a downloaded copy of Doom, the WAD files should be in there. Get them out of that DOSBox setup, move them to GZDoom on your main OS and you should be in business.

FWIW, after writing this answer I went and downloaded GZDoom, found a WAD for the demo version of Doom and I was in business. Screenshot below. Note that the graphic textures are still pixelated, but the edges of surfaces are now smooth like a vector rendered 3D game. Not perfect, but an improvement over 100% rasterized 3D graphics.

[image: GZDoom screenshot.]

Comment: it worked.Graphics is much better than before Is there some other tricks so I could improve the graphics of game more ? Excuse me if i am becoming more greedy.

Comment: @DevParzival I don’t know. I am not an expert on how this stuff works. I just know that it does. GZDoom seems to have a healthy community of users and solid documentation; spend some time and explore it to see what you can do to make your setup of Doom better.

Comment: If you Google something like "[zdoom enhanced textures](https://www.google.com/search?q=zdoom+enhanced+textures)", you should get some links to texture replacement packs that ideally improve the look of the game.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're becoming too greedy. GZDoom is as good as it's going to get, because those textures and sprites were made as you said nearly 30 years ago. They were not made to take advantage of future graphics features, they were a very very small company back then. The only other thing you could look for us a high res textures pwad file to supplement them. But the engine and effects is still going to be the same experience.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have experience with ZDoom/GZDoom, but I have used Doomsday engine which works much in the same way: You drop in your WAD, and you are good to go. With Doomsday you can play with the vanilla textures and sprites or you can add community-developed resource packs to improve sound, music, textures and change monsters from 2D sprites to 3D models.